# How do I merge two arrays to create one array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Imagine I've got two arrays in JavaScript:

```
var geoff = ['one', 'two'];
var degeoff = ['three', 'four'];
```

How do I merge the two arrays, resulting in an array like this?

```
var geoffdegeoff = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var geoffdegeoff = geoff.concat(degeoff);
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across this and thought to add an additional way.

note: I see you want to create a third new var.

.concat is good, but you have to create a new array (unless you override the orig).

How about if you want to merge/combine array "second" into array "first".

Here is a nifty way.

```
// using apply
var first = ['aa','bb','cc'];
var second = ['dd','ee'];
first.push.apply(first, second);
first;
```

or

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(first, second); 
first;
```

Comment: `Array.prototype` == `[]` :)

Comment: I get what you are saying, but by passing in "first" as "this", we are changing/applying the second in place. I hope I get what you mean. lol.

Comment: I don't think you actually got my point; `[].push.apply(first, second)` is what I mean :)

Comment: This will be useful for big arrays, whereby truly appending data prevents a full array copy.

Comment: @Jack: While the substitution is valid in this case, `Array.prototype != []`.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, they're not identical in the sense that entering it on the console will give you `true`, merely saving some type work.

Comment: You were right, I misread what you were going for. Yeah, I 'get' now what you were meaning. lol. thanks.